# Merging elf shared-objects

Tags: linux, elf

Let say I have libA.so and libB.so, is there any way for me to combine them into a single shared library libC.so that contains all exported symbols of both libA.so and libB.so?

Comment: I assume that you do not have the source code of these libraries (just to make things clear!). But, have you access to a static version (`*.a`) of it ?

Comment: No, I have neither source code nor static version.

Answer (score 2):

Quite frankly this is rather a development (i.e. StackOverflow) question than RCE, but let me give the level of advice I can give with the level of information you provided in your question.

The question is whether what you want to achieve is to have those symbols available through a single library by all means or whether you don't care *how* both sets of symbols are made available to your program(s).

If you insist on the library, you could simply write *one* shared library and export the symbols from it through shallow wrapper functions, but use the dynamic loader to find them from the originating shared objects (check out [`ldd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) and related man pages). It is not too difficult to find all symbol names with [`readelf --dyn-syms <elf-file>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf)/`readelf --syms --use-dynamic <elf-file>` (the package on Ubuntu/Debian is `elfutils`). From the output of that you can write a version script to use in your linker (e.g. `gcc -Wl,--version-script,script.map ...`).

However, assuming you use the default Linux facilities with no additional magic involved, you can also abuse the [`ld-linux`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux)/[`ld.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so) approach of locating the symbols. If you write a simple wrapper shell script that sets `LD_PRELOAD`, you can simply load both shared objects up front and they should - under normal circumstances - take precedence over other symbols. It's also commonly used as a debugging technique.

I strongly suggest you read chapters 41 and 42 of Michael Kerrisks excellent book "The Definitive Guide to Linux and Unix System Programming", colloquially known as [TLPI](http://man7.org/tlpi/index.html). The respective [source samples](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/all_files_by_chapter.html#ch42) may come in handy, too, in your case.